# Favorite etiquette (and hot questions)

Tags: support, etiquette, bookmarks, hot-questions

I am well aware of how the Favorite button on the questions works and where I go to find my or anyone else's favorite questions.

I am also well aware of the fact that adding a question to the favorites improves its "hotness score" (and who does not want to show his answers on the main page), since it is public reputation of the question. Correct me if I am wrong.

Adding 1 and 1 made me look into the profiles of some highly-ranked users (on various sites) and the amount of the favorite questions closely matched the amount of their answers. The OP can do probably the same for his questions, but highly-ranked askers are not so common.

Yes. I know that hot questions are not substitute for a good questions and good answers, but the visibility helps.

Everyone have limited amount of votes per day, which affects questions all around, but are the Favorites limited in any way? Is this considered as ethical or is it advisable?

Comment: Unless something changed recently, I don't think *favoriting* will increase hotness. *Upvoting* will of course. But of course you can't upvote your own posts.

Comment: Considering that most of the HNQ questions right now have very few favorites, I'm pretty sure there's no correlation between the two. Favorites are just questions you want to keep track of for some reason... it may even be because you *don't* like them... I'm also not sure how favorited questions correlate to the people who have answered them. Someone who answers a question doesn't really need to favorite it because it will stay in their answer history.

Comment: If you are concerned that an answerer may wish to increase the chance of the question reaching Hot Network Questions, in order to attract upvotes to their answer, they are already free to upvote the question and every answer it has, all of which will increase its hotness score (unless votes by answerers are disregarded in the hotness calculation?).

Comment: @Catija I also see some HNQs have barely any up votes either. [This one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314738), for example, has one up vote, and no favorites currently. It's weird, but maybe because it's a niche site?

Comment: It's probably in the sidebar already but here's the way HNQs are decided: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/284336 Nothing in that is number of favorites. Updated method: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/284336

Comment: @Laurel It has 3 answers, which have lots of votes. Number of answers and their votes have a lot to do with the hotness rating, too. See my previous comment.... but now that I'm looking at it again, I think that's an old version. I think the new one doesn't include number of views.

Comment: @gnat That makes sense. In that case, what could make the users to fave all the question their answered?

Comment: hard to tell for sure, maybe some use favorites to track if there are updates to question or new answers to it