# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a "Hot" questions tab?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, hot-questions

Stack Overflow lacks a "Hot" questions tab. However, the other sites (Server Fault, Super User, and Meta Stack Overflow) possess this Tab.

Was this intentional? That is, to avoid "loitering" in Hot Questions, and encourage people to spend more time in Unanswered questions.

Or was the "Active" Tab its new replacement, simply renamed to sound more professional? I know little about the "Hot" ranking algorithm vs. the "Active" ranking algorithm, so it is entirely possible they are one in the same. (Although, judging from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-and-active-questions), I don't think this is the case.)

**Edit:**
The following is what I see:
[image: No Hot Tab]

As it turns out, [Gamecat's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91650/why-doesnt-stackoverflow-have-a-hot-questions-tab/91655#91655) is correct, as the Hot tab is not present on the "Questions" page. The above image is what is shown on the "Questions" page.

Comment: They both exist, but they're apparently confusing enough that someone created an FAQ entry just to help people tell them apart: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-and-active-questions

Comment: Yup, it's there. Now give me some of that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confused by the several views.

The front page is visble by clicking on the stack overflow logo. This view has a "hot" tab.

The questions page, is visible by clicking the "questions" button. This view lacks the "hot" tab.