# How is "active question" defined?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “hot” and “active” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-and-active-questions)

In the questions/active view, there are a lot of questions without any answers/votes/views, so I don't understand what constitutes an active question. How is "activity" measured?