# How do I make question active of other users?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, active, question-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

There was a question with same description asked 8 months ago. It was no longer active. There is no point in asking same question(exact duplicate).

I have read [What is the difference between "hot" and "active" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-and-active-questions) It says that *active* means "with recent activity." I have written a comment on the question; though, it didn't become active. The question becomes active by writing a new answer, editing the question, or any answer for that question.

I found three ways to make question active but I don't see any feasible way:

1. Editing the question - I think there is no point in editing question without reason.
2. Offering a bounty- I don't want to invest any bounty for that question.
3. Answering the question, and deleting the answer- there is no point in doing stupid things like this.

   - How do I make a question active, so that people will see that question?
   - Is there any simple method to make a question active?

Comment: It seems other than bounty there is no any way to make question of others active. I haven't thought this question will be said as duplicate of How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?

Comment: Which question? If it was asked 8 months ago and seems answerable, is it missing some key piece of information? Would answering it just take more time than most people would give? What is stopping people from providing answers? If you can figure that out and fix it, then an edit _would_ seem to be in order.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk You are trying to get more attention to a question asked from somebody else, if I correctly understand what you wrote; that is not different from getting attention from your old questions.

Comment: Can I edit question and tell I had same problem. Is this feasible?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk No, that is not the correct way to edit a question. That would eventually be a comment, but it should not be added to a question.

Comment: What should I do? There is completely opposite views of moderator and 20k+ user? Both are trusted users. How can this discussion question getting downvotes?

Comment: Once again question is closed because it has similar title but there was no perfect solution of it. There were different suggestions of moderator & 23k+ user. What should I do if I have this kind of situation?

Comment: I don't think this was an exact dupe, but it will need some editing prior to re-opening. This is basically 'what do I do if some old unanswered question gets in my way of asking something?' (and that does happen from time to time)

Comment: @ Tim Post♦:Can you please edit question in well format and reopen it?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk If you really care about it, *you* can edit it, which was the entire point of my answer.

Comment: Please don't edit out the duplicate link from the top of the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This unfortunately happens from time to time. Without looking at the question, I really can't help you figure out what's wrong with it. If it was asked eight months ago and has not received answers, *something* is wrong with it. Ask yourself the following questions:

- Is the question too broad, or difficult to understand?
- Is the question missing key pieces of information that are needed to provide answers?
- Does the question show no effort on the part of the author?
- Would answering the question simply take more time than most people in our community care to spend?
- Is the question tagged appropriately?

All of the above items are things ***you can probably fix*** with an edit.

If you think the existing question could not be fixed without radically changing it, flag it for our attention and let us know. If it's eight months old with no answers and blocking a similar but potentially better question along the same lines, we'll probably be happy to close it in order to get it out of your way.

If there is absolutely ***nothing*** wrong with the existing question, then you'll have to try your luck with the bounty system. You can also conveniently share links to the question in order to get it more attention.

Again, the best answer I can give you is it depends on the question. Without seeing the question, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course propose an edit to the question that *improves* it. If the question wasn't answered the first time then one reason may be that it was un-answerable, because it lacked detail, or poorly described the problem (at least in the opinion of the people who saw the question).

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you have to contribute is a desire to see some activity on the question, the bounty is the way to do it.  Having a comment make a question active is simply a <strike>cheap</strike> free way of getting attention for it.  Since comments can be deleted and not viewed (except by mods), it's not obvious to even high ranking users what is going on. A person could comment, make the question active, then delete the comment later.  This could be done repeatedly. I don't see any reason to change it and allow comments to make a question active.

<sub>I honestly don't know if adding a comment changes this state or not, but am assuming it doesn't based on the OP's description.  If it does, then I would suggest that it shouldn't.</sub>

Comment: Moderators can see the deleted comments left for any post.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, but they would have to be looking for this type of behavior.  granted they could detect egregious abuse when they saw it, but it would make it pretty easy to avoid bounties and still get attention for an old question.

Comment: I was commenting on "except by mods, presumably." Moderators are not notified when a user add a comment, and then deletes it, except in the case the comment is for the post written by a moderator, and in that case the moderator who wrote the post would be notified. As such, moderators cannot take action in such cases, also because deleted comments are not like deleted answers: Moderators see the deleted comments in a separate page, even if that page is linked from the post.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I see, so it's even worse that I was describing.